# ColdFusion make new rows

Tags: coldfusion, output

I've got a cfoutput outputting some query data to display a product list on my page.

```
<ul class="row">
<cfoutput query="mycontent" startrow="#url.startrow#" maxrows="#url.maxrows#">
  <li class="span-3">item data here</li>
    <cfif mycontent.currentrow MOD 3 IS 3>
     </ul><ul class="row">
    </cfif>
</cfouptut>
```

I am trying to make it appear as a new row, with a new set of `<ul>` tags, when the items equal 3. This way I can have it neatly displayed on my page.

Each time it loads, it won't do this correctly. Instead it keeps the content within the top most `<ul>` tags.

How I can get this to be structured in a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want `MOD` to be `0` as `MOD` returns the remainder. That's how you know you are on a row divisible by `3` because the remainder equals `0`.

```
<ul class="row">
<cfoutput query="mycontent" startrow="#url.startrow#" maxrows="#url.maxrows#">
  <li class="span-3">item data here</li>
    <cfif mycontent.currentrow MOD 3 eq 0>
     </ul><ul class="row">
    </cfif>
</cfouptut>
```

> MOD or %
>   [Modulus]: Return the remainder after a number is divided by a divisor. The result has the same sign as the divisor. The value to the right of the operator should be an integer; using a non-numeric value causes an error, and if you specify a real number, ColdFusion ignores the fractional part (for example, 11 MOD 4.7 is 3).

Comment: I think i love you. thank you for explaining it to me. i never quite understood how it worked until now. Greatly appreciated